Combinar dos plots para que aparezcan de manera continua, uno al lado del otro
Estoy intentando que en la siguiente imagen, en vez de que salga una línea sobrepuesta en otra, aparezca primero la línea naranja y luego seguida la azul, pero no una sobrepuesta en la otra.
No sé si esto es posible o que, ya que cada línea procede de un DataFrame diferente, donde uno es una serie normal y la línea naranja es una predicción sobre los datos reales.

El código utilizado es:
plt.figure(figsize = (8,4))
plt.plot(y,label='datos reales')
plt.plot(modelo.predict(X), label='predicción')
plt.legend()
plt.show()


Puedes usar subplots y compartir los ejes entre ellos (el eje y en este caso):
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np


# Algunos datos aleatorios de muestra
x = np.arange(1, 51, 1)
data1 = np.random.randint(20, size=50)
data2 = np.random.randint(20, size=50)

# Definir los dos subplots
fig = plt.figure()
gs = fig.add_gridspec(1, 2, wspace=0)
ax1, ax2 = gs.subplots(sharey=True)

# Graficar
ax1.plot(x, data1, color="orange")
ax2.plot(x, data2, color="deepskyblue")

# Ocultar las marcas del eje y del segundo subplot
ax2.tick_params(axis='y', which='both', left=False)

plt.show()


Si quieres eliminar también la linea vertical del eje:
ax2.spines['left'].set_visible(False)


